# Сложные предложения: ставить тире или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Везде ли знаки препинания и стилистика верны?

> Не важно, какое количество положительного заряда и интереса вы имеете, — после такой работы жалоб и нытья из-за нехватки острых ощущений не избежать.
>
> Как бы солидно и богато эта должность ни звучала, быть руководителем банковского филиала — это одна из наиболее скучных и неинтересных работ.
>
> Такая работа — это нудная канитель, которая истощает мозг.
>
> Единственное, что могло бы, вероятно, сделать человека заинтересованным в данной работе — это хорошая зарплата.
>
> Работать с числами может быть легко, но когда вам придётся иметь дело с ними каждый день – это адски скучно.
>
> Бухгалтерская работа часто требует от вас быть целеустремленным и оптимистичным — эти качества понадобятся, чтобы продержаться целый день.

Answer (score 1):

***Не важно, какое количество положительного заряда и интереса вы имеете, — после такой работы жалоб и нытья из-за нехватки острых ощущений не избежать.*** Знаки расставлены верно, в БСП между частями отношения противительные.

***Как бы солидно и богато эта должность ни звучала, быть руководителем банковского филиала — это одна из наиболее скучных и неинтересных работ.*** Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

***Такая работа — это нудная канитель, которая истощает мозг.*** Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

***Единственное, что могло бы, вероятно, сделать человека заинтересованным в данной работе, — это хорошая зарплата.*** Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Ставим запятую после придаточного предложения перед тире.

***Работать с числами, может быть, легко, но, когда вам придётся иметь дело с ними каждый день, это адски скучно.*** Тире не ставим: *но ... это адски скучно*, вместо тире запятая, завершающая придаточное. На стыке союзов *но, когда* нужна запятая. Вводное слово *может быть* тоже обособляем.

***Бухгалтерская работа часто требует от вас быть целеустремленным и оптимистичным: эти качества понадобятся, чтобы продержаться целый день.***  Здесь БСП, в котором, на мой взгляд,  вторая часть указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой части. Основная часть высказывания заключена в первой части. Поэтому ставим двоеточие.

Но и тире в последнем предложении тоже возможно, так как вторая часть имеет и присоединительное значение. ***Бухгалтерская работа часто требует от вас быть целеустремленным и оптимистичным — эти качества понадобятся, чтобы продержаться целый день.***

Answer (score 0):

Неважно, какое количество положительного заряда и интереса вы имеете, – после такой работы жалоб и нытья из-за нехватки острых ощущений не избежать (тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении).

Как бы солидно и богато эта должность не звучала, быть руководителем банковского филиала – это одна из наиболее скучных и неинтересных работ (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым).

Такая работа – это нудная канитель, которая истощает мозг (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым).

Единственное, что могло бы, вероятно, сделать человека заинтересованным в данной работе, – это хорошая зарплата  (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым).

Работать с числами может быть легко, но когда вам придётся иметь дело с ними каждый день – это адово скучно (тире в сложноподчиненной части предложения).

Бухгалтерская работа часто требует от вас быть целеустремленным и оптимистичным – эти качества понадобятся, чтобы продержаться целый день (тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении).